# documentation on arguements?

Tags: documentation

I have seen many different parameters or arguments that can be passed to a query. For example, category_*in, category*_and term_id to name a few. Some of these can be found by using print_r to print out the object. ( If I have that right ). Others like the category__in I have been unable to find in codex. Is there a trick to learning about these parameters? How do I find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're all in the codex page for [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: Thanks Milo. It's funny that doing a direct search in the codex for category__in does not bring up that information

Answer (score 3):

As a compliment to **[Milo's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/69343/13418)** answer and [WP_Query Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) entry above, here is a nice little cheat-sheet and reference which summarizes the `$arguments` used with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query);

**WordPress Query Comprehensive Reference**
[`https://gist.github.com/2023628`](https://gist.github.com/2023628)
<sup>Compiled by luetkemj - [luetkemj.com](http://luetkemj.com)</sup>

...and here's a little gist to go along with it for debugging your query,

**Debugging WP_Query**
[`https://gist.github.com/3699573`](https://gist.github.com/3699573)
<sup>from [wpsmith](https://gist.github.com/wpsmith)</sup>

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wps_debug' );
function wps_debug() {
    global $wp_query;
    if( isset( $_GET['debug'] ) ) {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r( $wp_query ); echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

PS. this is just a quick and dirty way to see whats going on. There are other *tools*, *snippets* and *plugins* that do this in a more organized fashion. But that's a discussion for another time.

Answer (score 0):

All of those are in the Codex.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

I feel guilty about posting this as an answer but it does very directly answer your questions, "Is there a trick to learning about these parameters?" and "How do I find them?"

The trick is to search the Codex, and to read the Codex. Follow the links in the Codex. Look in the source code, a link to which is provided in many, but not all, of the Codex entries.

Yes, `print_r()` helps a lot. `var_dump()` is better in that it will output information even for empty strings, NULLs, booleans, etc. Its output is harder to read, but you get used to it.

Comment: Why do you feel guilty?

Comment: Mostly link answers are discouraged.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Shame on you!

Answer (score 0):

The code itself is also a great place to learn about all possible arguments. One advantage over all the other methods (including the Codexs) is that it never gets outdated. Here's the code for WP_Query: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/query.php

The arguments you are referring to are in its `parse_tax_query` method.